# Given a set of activities, which have associated weights, choose the set of non-overlapping activities that will maximize the total weight

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, binary-search

I have been thinking and searching for the solution of this problem,found this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem#Weighted_Activity_Selection_Problem)

The solution proposes that find the activity with finish time <= start time for i.
But,consider this example:

starting-time:[1,2,3,4,5]

ending-time:[3,4,5,6,7]

respective-weight:[13,5,2,4,1]

For this example,when I am on activity:(4-6),I will be having 2 activities whose finishing time is less than 4,so,instead of just searching for a number through binary search,shouldn't we return an array and then take the max, value from it.

Please correct me if I misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the article, `opt[i] = MAX(opt[i-1], opt[t] + w(i))`, that is, `opt[i]` takes into account all activities that end before the `i`-th. That's why there is no need to iterate over all possible options.

Comment: can you please tell what would would be the value of opt[t] when I am on activity:(4-6)?

Comment: @ssharma 2 (we can take only one activity before it)

Comment: That means you chose activity 3-5,but then the 2 activities will overlap.

Comment: @ssharma I got it slightly wrong. `opt[t]` is 13 (we can pick only one activity and the first one is heaviest).